# su - <username> isn't working, it was working earlier

Tags: linux, centos, su

I have Linux Centos 7 installed,

Recently I created a user named oracle, when I ran `su - oracle`. It worked fine until an hour ago. Now, if I type `su - oracle`, nothing appears on the terminal, no message, no error. It is returned to the root user where the `su` command was written.

This is my `/etc/passwd`

```
oracle:x:1501:1501:oracle:/home/oracle:/bin/bash
```

This is the return of `su` command

```
[root@localhost /]# su - oracle

Último inicio de sesión:lun jul  1 20:41:41 -03 2019en pts/0

[root@localhost /]# su oracle
[root@localhost /]
```

**Where I can see logs to check what is the problem?**

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen. What is the output of the `id` command, before and after you run `su`?